# Hide Or Remove Div section

Tags: html, css, hide

I want to hide or remove the breadcrumb-wrapper div section from website. The essence of doing this is to remove the white space in the page title section of the website. The link to the website is found below:

> http://hp.harrypotterfans.shop/product-category/harry-potter-clothings/hoodie/

Comment: and your code ? so people can take a look at it first ?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
#breadcrumb-wrapper {
   display: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Just what I wanted. what of if i want to display just 5 or 10 of the white space. How will the code be structured?

Comment: #breadcrumb-wrapper {
    padding: 60px 0;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
} maybe you should remove those ;) please check if that's what you want, then you can use height and line-height attributes to suit your needs